# Socket IO using long polling instead of sockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm just getting started again with Node and Socket IO. I'm using socket.io v1.3.7.
I can load the socket IO client but it is long polling instead of using sockets.

The last time I used socketIO it worked fine. I think that was the 0.9.x branch.

`http://sockettest.dev:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1447350154198-2&sid=eW7B_kpSat6WfGQSAAAC`

Here's the code..

**Server - app.js**

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('connection', 'connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.emit('disconnection', 'not connected');
    });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

**Client - index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="//recently.dev:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('<?php echo '//' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ':3000/'; ?>');
socket.on('connection', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
</head> 
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is why..

[Why is my socket.io using long polling instead of the websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282578/why-is-my-socket-io-using-long-polling-instead-of-the-websocket)

I think older approach was better IMO. There should at least be an option.