# Socket.io with Laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-10

I'm learning a little Laravel and want to try websockets with Socket.io. I found several tuts, but they're all quite old.
A thing that I saw is that nowadays Laravel suggests to have Laravel Echo on the client side and some other libraries (more or less all commercial) as 'drivers' between Laravel's Events and the client.
Laravel once had laravel-echo-server, but having a look inside its code I see that it still supports Socket.io v2.3.0, while currently it's v4. So I guess I cannot use laravel-echo-server.

So what I cannot fully understand is:

- If I want to use socket.io, do I really need Laravel Echo?
- And if yes, since laravel-echo-server is not compatible with socket.io v4, is there anything else I can use instead? Any other way?

Laravel 10 docs do not mention Socket.io, nor laravel-echo-server. Only Laravel Echo.
Laracasts has a very old (2015) video course in which explains socket.io with redis. No Laravel Echo, nor laravel-echo-server. But it's 2015.

So, how should I move nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've touched on this a little before in this answer here: [Why do we need products like Pusher and Socket.io to establish a websocket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611103/why-do-we-need-products-like-pusher-and-socket-io-to-establish-a-websocket-conne/44611468#44611468)

But basically, yes, Laravel Echo Server is abandoned and Laravel's own documentation falls short in describing how best to wire up all of the necessary parts in order to roll your own Websocket server. And for good reason: Rolling your own Websocket Server and Client implementation for use in Laravel is no trivial feat, and there are a number of things you will need to consider in order to handle this.

Additionally, a single answer on StackOverflow will fall extremely short in covering everything you'll need for you to roll out your Websocket Server and client.

That said, probably the best place to start would be to begin looking through how Laravel registers its [Broadcasters](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/10.x/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters).

These are responsible for sending your events out through to your Websocket server through some kind of medium. Back when Laravel Echo Server was actually a thing, the Redis Broadcast Driver was often used (using [predis/predis](https://github.com/predis/predis) under the hood) to send out messages using Redis' pub/sub notifications along with a Queue Worker process responsible for managing these events.

The Laravel Echo Server would in turn subscribe to these events and broadcast out messages to all connected clients based on these server events.

The [Socket.io Server API Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/) has a fair bit of valuable information on setting up a lot of the basics in terms of not just listening for message events, but also Redis events as well.

Unfortunately, I don't have much to offer beyond this as the scope of your question is too broad to cover every possible detail. Hopefully this gets you a good start and you can narrow things down as you explore more into how Laravel and Websockets work with each other.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that probably for now the best way to use websockets in Laravel without commercial tools is Sokety, which is (almost) free and if really  needed, at least offes paid support. But it uses uWebSockets.js instead of Socket.io.